# Facebook Like-box doesn't work with specific sites

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I see a weird kind of fail working with like box... I can't see the like box, but the address looks fine:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/instituto.vannghiespana"
                 data-width="292" data-height="570" data-show-faces="true"
                 data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>
```

I have tried changing the “http” for “https” and still doesn’t answer. Even when I try to generate the code on like box facebook developers site, the validation says the code is ok, but I still can’t see the site.

But... When I use the older website:

```
data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Instituto-Van-Nghi-Espa%C3%B1a/133758943312622"
```

Works fine.

Thanks for your time.

(EDITED)

I already include the facebook sniplet after body

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

even I try changing js.src = "//connect for js.src = "http//connect

Any ideas?

Nacho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook Like Box plugin is for liking Facebook Pages.
The example you listed, `instituto.vannghiespana`, is a (fake) profile, not a page.

The like box plugin cannot be used with profiles. If this is your profile you should convert it to a Page (for one thing, a profile can't have more than 5000 friends)

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting the JavaScript code:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId={{APP_ID}}";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Look more carefully in [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

Answer (score 0):

do you have the required fb-root html tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

as well as the corresponding javascript code?